# inserção.jsp adicionar valor inteiro

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <% 
          try{
              Disciplina dcp = new Disciplina();
              DAODisciplina dcd = new DAODisciplina();
              String nome_disciplina = request.getParameter("nome_disciplina"); 
              int cargahoraria_disciplina = request.getParameter("cargahoraria_disciplina");
              
              if(nome_disciplina.equals(null)){
                  response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
              }else{
                  dcp.setNome_dcpn(nome_disciplina);
                  dcp.setCargah_dcpn(cargahoraria_disciplina);
                  dcd.insertDisciplina(dcp);
              }              
          }catch(Exception erro){
              throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao inserir Disciplina: ",erro);
          }
          
        %>   
   
    </body>
</html>
```

A dao o valor para cargahoraria esta como inteiro porem ao adicionar na jsp retorna o erro
String cannot be converted to int

algumas tentativas não retornaram erro de codigo porem ao executar não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

O parâmetro enviado é uma string. Logo, você precisa transformar em inteiro.

```java
// recebe como String
String cargaHorariaParameter = request.getParameter("cargahoraria_disciplina");

// cria um inteiro
int cargahoraria_disciplina = Integer.parseInt(cargaHorariaParameter);
```